# How to add strings and integers to an array then print to a text file

Tags: c, arrays, file, io

Goodday, when I get to entering the first name of the student, the program immediately crashes. Also I'm not exactly sure how to add the names and the ID into an array to print to the text file. May I have some assistance please?

```
struct records{
    int id;
    char fname[15];
    char lname[15];
    };
struct records student;


 int max=1000;
        int i;
        srand( time(NULL) ); //random numbers generated
        ATND= fopen("Student Record.txt","a");
        if(ATND== NULL){
            printf("ERROR!");       
            exit(1);
        }
        for(i=0; i<100; i++){
        printf("Enter student\'s first name: ");
        scanf("%s", student.fname[i]);

        printf("\n\n");
        printf("Enter student\'s last name: ");
        scanf("%s", student.lname[i]);

        /*randomnumber*/student.id[i]=rand() %max + 39048543;

        fprintf(ATND,"%s %s %d", student.fname[i], student.lname[i], student.id[i]);
    }
        fclose(ATND);
```

Comment: yes it is @Aleksandar

Comment: post the definition of `student`.

Comment: @chux the definition has been added

Answer (score 1):

Code only provides data space for 1 record whereas it appears to need 1000 records.  Number of other issues.  Suspect after 10 hours, OP has worked a number of them

```
//Definition - good
struct records {
  int id;
  char fname[15];  // IMO 15 is too limiting for first and last
  char lname[15];
};

// Only 1 student, need many more
// struct records student;
#define STUDENT_N 1000
struct records student[STUDENT_N];

void read_records(void) {
  // avoid magic numbers
  // int max = 1000;
  int max = STUDENT_N;

  int i;
  srand(time(NULL)); //random numbers generated

  // ATND not declared
  FILE *ATND;

  ATND = fopen("Student Record.txt", "a");
  if (ATND == NULL) {
    printf("ERROR!");
    exit(1);
  }

  char buf[100];

  // avoid magic numbers
  // for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  for (i = 0; i < STUDENT_N; i++) {

    printf("Enter student\'s first name: ");
    // don't use scanf()
    // scanf("%s", student.fname[i]);
    if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) break;
    if (sscanf(buf, "%14s", student[i].fname) != 1) break;

    printf("\n\n");
    printf("Enter student\'s last name: ");
    // Add flush to insure buffered prompts that do not end in \n are sent
    fflush(stdout);

    // scanf("%s", student.lname[i]);
    if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) break;
    if (sscanf(buf, "%14s", student[i].lname) != 1) break;

    // /*randomnumber*/student.id[i] = rand() % max + 39048543;
    /*randomnumber*/student[i].id = rand() % max + 39048543;

    // Do not index the name, index the structure
    // fprintf(ATND, "%s %s %d", student.fname[i], student.lname[i],    student.id[i]);
    fprintf(ATND, "%s %s %d", student[i].fname, student[i].lname,  student[i].id);
  }
  fclose(ATND);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the correction. Well appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming student.fname is a char array of sufficient size

```
    scanf("%s", student.fname[i]);
```

should be

```
scanf("%s", student.fname);
```

You need to pass a pointer to the beginning of the array, NOT the value of the chars, one by one.  scanf will enter the entire name in one call.

Comment: i change them. Now when I enter the last name the program crashes

Comment: Have you made the same change to  scanf("%s", student.lname[i]);